# Consulta SQL/Java

Tags: java, sql, ormlite

Bom dia, galera sou iniciante em SQL e preciso fazer a seguinte busca.

```
Tenho esta tabela:
MINIMO    MAXIMO      CLASSE
    0        20         1
    21       40         2
    41       60         3 
    60       10000      4
```

Preciso de um comando para ver qual classe se encaixa o número 32. Mais precisamente estou usando o ORMLITE no Java

Comment: Tenta isso: seuDAO.queryBuilder().selectColumns("name").where().le("minimo", 32).and().ge("maximo", 32);

Comment: Alguma resposta ajudou a resolver o problema e pode sanar dúvidas similares de outros usuários? Caso positivo não esqueça de marcar a resposta como aceita. Pra fazer isso é só clicar no ✓ do lado esquerdo da mesma (abaixo do indicador de up e down votes).

Answer (score 1):

Considerando que você está utilizando o [OrmLite](http://ormlite.com/) e que você quer um resultado semelhante a:

```
SELECT classe
  FROM tabela
 WHERE 32 BETWEEN minimo AND maximo
```

Precisaremos criar uma `query` usando o `queryBuilder` do Dao. Segundo a [documentação do where](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/com/j256/ormlite/stmt/Where.html) teremos:

```
Dao<Tabela, String> dao;
List<Tabela> resultados;

dao = DaoManager.createDao(conexao, Tabela.class);
resultados = dao.queryBuilder()
        .where()
        .le("mini‌​mo", 32)
        .and()
        .ge("maximo", 32)
        .query();

for (Tabela tabela : resultados) {
  System.out.println(tabela.getClasse());
}
```

> `le` adiciona uma cláusula '<=' para que a coluna seja menor-que ou igual ao valor.
>
> `ge` adiciona uma cláusula '>=' para que a coluna seja maior-que ou igual ao valor.

Answer (score -1):

Você pode fazer assim:

```
SELECT `CLASSE` FROM `nome_da_tabela` WHERE `MINIMO` <= 30 AND `MAXIMO`  >= 30;
```

Comment: pesquise também BETWEEN

Comment: Na realidade ele especificou que está usando ORMLITE, ou seja, não é uma query exatamente que ele quer